# Angular 2 generate table rows with detail rows from array

Tags: arrays, angular, html-table, master-detail

I have following array:

```
{Test1:aaa,Test2:bbb, Test3:ccc, Test4: ddd, Test5: eee},
{Test1:aaa,Test2:bbb, Test3:ccc, Test4: ddd1, Test5: eee1},
{Test1:aaa,Test2:bbb, Test3:ccc, Test4: ddd2, Test5: eee2},
{Test1:aaa,Test2:bbb, Test3:ccc, Test4: ddd3, Test5: eee3},
...
```

The table result looks like this:

```
 Test1    Test2    Test3   Test4   Test5
 aaa      bbb      ccc     ddd     eee
 aaa      bbb      ccc     ddd1    eee1
 aaa      bbb      ccc     ddd2    eee2
 aaa      bbb      ccc     ddd3    eee3
```

But I need to have table with detail view like this:

```
 Test1    Test2    Test3   
 aaa      bbb      ccc     
   ddd     eee
   ddd1    eee1
   ddd2    eee2
   ddd3    eee3
 aaa1     ...       ...
 ...
```

How can I generate this table in template? 
I have following script already:

```
<table>
              <colgroup>
                <col *ngFor="let column of columns" [ngStyle]="{'width': column.ratio}">
              </colgroup>
              <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let row of dataset; let index=index; let odd=odd; let even=even" 
                [ngClass]="{ odd: odd, alt: even, selectedRow: selectedRow===index }" (click)="select(index)" (dblclick)="dblClickF($event,row)" >

                <td *ngFor="let col of row | values; let first = first;"  [ngClass]="{'first unpack':first}" (click)="unpack(row,first)">{{col}}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
              </table>
```

Can you help me please? (any plunkr?)

Comment: Where does for example aaa1 comes from? You should specify more precisely your desired result, I don't think its clear from the example..

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a component that calls itself if it has more children, you can use `ComponentFactoryResolver` inside the same component and viewContainerRef to place the new created component under the old one, check these two plunkers that i created and see if it helps:

Expand children data with a click:
https://plnkr.co/HETv1d

Recursive expand children:
https://plnkr.co/WcduaE

Also, your data structure would be easier to work if it looked like this:

```
[
  {"Test1":"aaa",
   "children": [
     {"name" : "Name1"},
     {"name" : "Name2"},
     {"name" : "name3"},
     {"name" : "name4"}
   ]},
  {"Test2": "bbb",
     "children": [
     {"name" : "Name1"},
     {"name" : "Name2"},
     {"name" : "name3"},
     {"name" : "name4"}
  ]},
  {"Test3": "ccc",
     "children": [
     {"name" : "Name1"},
     {"name" : "Name2"},
     {"name" : "name3"},
     {"name" : "name4"}
  ]}
]
```